# Multiline strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore

I have a "multiline" string in my database that looks something like this:

`This
is
a
multiline
string`

I'm using Google's "Datstore" so it looks exactly like this in the viewer. There are no `\n`'s or things like that.

The problem is that when I try to set the retrieved string to a Javascript variable, I get an "ILLEGAL TOKEN" error. I'm setting it via Jinja2 so it looks like this:

```
<script>
var multilinestring = {{body|safe}} 
</script>
```

I set other variables like this as well, but they are all integers or single line strings. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a multi line string, than you must have a new line character at the end of each line (e.g \n)

You can use the replace filter and see if you can remove the new line character
e.g.

```
var multilinestring = {{body|safe|replace("\n", " ")}} // not tested
```

Comment: Thanks but this just put a space. It did solve the errors though. I think @GAEfan's answer of putting the `\` is right, if only it will work.

Comment: I think his code was cut in the comment, you can use replace("\n", "\\n")

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap them in quotation marks.
Try
    var multilinestring = ''{{ body|safe}}";

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do to JSON encode the string.

That will take care of any new lines as well as other special characters.

I don't know the server-side stuff to encode, but on the client it would look something like:

```
var multilinestring = JSON.parse(jsonEncodeStringHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript strings cannot span multiple lines without a trailing backslash.  That is the token error

Try:

var multilinestring = "{{body|safe|replace('\n', '\')}}";

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it should fix it, but I'm getting the following syntax error:  `var authorBio = "{{bio|safe|replace("\n","\")}}";`
`TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got ';'`

Comment: You are not using the quotes correctly.  The inner should be single quotes. Else, you have made 4 strings.